# documentation for MiKTeX xelatex

Tags: xetex, miktex

On my Windows 10 system I regularly use MiKTeX's `xelatex` command:

```
hello.tex

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}

PS> xelatex hello
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.6) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.6.26)  28 JUN 2021 15:49
entering extended mode
...
Output written on hello.pdf
```

- it works fine, but I can't find any MiKTeX documentation for it:

- [MiKTeX Manual](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/) doesn't mention it
- `mthelp xelatex` returns "Documentation for xelatex could not be found."

As MiKTeX's `xelatex` is self-reporting to be XeTeX, I suppose it's a macro package around [miktex-xetex](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/miktex-xetex.html).

Where is MiKTeX's `xelatex` command defined?

Comment: xelatex is xetex + latex. You get a reference for xetex with `mthelp xetex-reference`

Comment: "Documentation for xetex-reference could not be found."

Comment: Relooking at this, I see that `xetex-reference.pdf` also has no mention of `xelatex`. As usual, the Arch linux guys come to the rescue - [LATEX(1)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/latex.1.en), "`xelatex` ... are formats based on the respective engines."